# jstl foreach omit an element in last record

Tags: jsp, jstl

trying to use this jstl to formulate a json string, how can i make the segment not to put a comma in the end of the last record? note the comma in the end

```
<c:forEach items="${fileList}" var="current">
    { id:1001,data:["<c:out value="${current.fileName}" />" , "<c:out value="${current.path}" />" , "<c:out value="${current.size}" />" , "<c:out value="${current.type}" />"] },
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: all elements need the }
but the last must not have the comma ,

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Just use [`LoopTagStatus#isLast()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#isLast()).

```
<c:forEach items="${fileList}" var="current" varStatus="loop">
    { id: 1001,
      data: [
        "<c:out value="${current.fileName}" />",
        "<c:out value="${current.path}" />",
        "<c:out value="${current.size}" />",
        "<c:out value="${current.type}" />"
      ]
    }<c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

You can also use the conditional operator in EL instead of `<c:if>`:

```
    ${!loop.last ? ',' : ''}
```

Comment: +1. A much better solution than mine. @nokheat: you should mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I never liked about JSTL (actually I think is the only thing :)) is the fact that there is no way to retrieve the size of a list/collection.

**EDIT:** ok, so it was possible but I didn't know it :( [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851880/check-a-collection-size-with-jstl).

The `forEach` tag has the `varStatus` attribute which you can use to determine the index of the row (`index`/`count` properties on the `varStatus` variable) but you have to test if you are at the last position in the list, that  means having the list size beforehand:

```
<c:forEach items="${fileList}" var="current" varStatus="status">
   ...
  <c:if test="${not (status.count eq listSize)}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

But you will have to place the `listSize` in scope, manually, before doing this sort of thing.

What I did in one of my projects was to create myself a tag that takes a collection and returns the value:

```
  <myLib:collectionSize collection="${fileList}" var="listSize" />
  <c:forEach items="${fileList}" var="current" varStatus="status">
     ...
    <c:if test="${not (status.count eq listSize)}">,</c:if>
  </c:forEach>
```

You could do the same if you have this sort of code often (else you can just add it in scope with whatever is convenient to you).

Comment: After a quick search I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851880/check-a-collection-size-with-jstl. Maybe it can help you even more.

Comment: since the list object has a size() function, can i use list.size to make it look more elegrant?

Comment: JSTL mainly goes for accessor fields "getProp" and "setProp" and in your JSP you will go for "prop". You could do "list.size" if the list had a method called "getSize" but id doesn't, it just has "size".

Comment: @nokheat: BalusC provided a more cleaner solution to your post. Go for his response.

Answer (score 3):

by [Check a collection size with JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851880/check-a-collection-size-with-jstl)
the answer were to use the functions tag

put this at the top of the page to allow the fn namespace

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

and use like this in your jsp page

```
<p>The length of the companies collection is : ${fn:length(companies)}</p>
```