# How can I check if a resultset returns more than one row in JSP?

Tags: jsp, resultset

I am trying to figure out how I can check if a stored sql procedure I am running will return more than one row as a resultset. I have a forEach method which prints out the rows, but I cannot seem to be able to check later weather the resultset is one or more rows. I only need to know how to check if the result is MORE than one row. All help is appreciated.
Here is a little snipplet of my jsp.

```
<tr>
<td>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ aStoredProcedure }">  
<fmt:formatNumber value="${ row.totalPrice }"pattern="#,##0.00"/>
<c:out value="${row.currency }"/>
(<c:out value="${ row.id }"/>)
</c:forEach>
</td>
</tr>
```

The above code works well and I included it here in case there is a way to use it somehow to check if there are more than one row returned (I had to rename some variables for liability reasons) but now I need to check weather or not the result gives more than one row, and I need to do this in a different table row.
So far I've tried:

```
<c:if test="${ aStoredProcedure >'1'}">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <%--do something here if it is bigger than 1--%>
  </td>
 </tr>
</c:if>
```

and

```
<c:if test="${ row >'1'}">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <%--do something here if it is bigger than 1--%>
  </td>
 </tr>
</c:if>
```

But these don't work at all.. only returns JasperExceptions. I found good solutions for how to check if a resultset has data or not, but nothing for how to do it entirely in JSP and preferably without using java. As you can probably tell, I am very new to JSP and will appreciate any help on how to figure out how to check if the procedure returns more than one result.

I have a controller class as a java class, which houses the model that I use to put the model in place:

```
model.put("aStoredProcedure",managerClass.nameofMethodICallFromMngrClass(aValueIUseToCallMethod(),anotherValueIUseToCallMethod()) );
```

and for the time being I had to add a new part to the model to get the check done:

```
model.put("aStoredProcedureSize",managerClass.nameofMethodICallFromMngrClass(aValueIUseToCallMethod(),anotherValueIUseToCallMethod()).size() );
```

I then check the size to be bigger than 1 before doing anything on the JSP side:

```
<c:if test="${ aStoredProcedureSize gt 1}">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <%--do what I want here--%>
  </td>
 </tr>
</c:if>
```

This works well and does what I want, but I had to make changes to the java side and was wondering if the checking of the size could be done somehow entirely on the JSP side without having to make a new part to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${ row >'1'}` gives you malformed XML, therefore the JasperException. Try

```
${ row gt 1 }
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, the gt seems to work well. However I noticed that I could not call the row from outside the original forEach which I determined it in, so I ended up creating a new piece of a model which I put in my controller class which is using regular java. So I ended up making a new "aStoredProcedureSize" model part in  which is the exact same piece of model as "aStoredProcedure" with the exception that I call .size() in the end of it. I was wondering if the .size could have been called in the JSP side of the code?

Comment: @ghoulfolk that's a different question, but this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851880/check-a-collection-size-with-jstl

Comment: yeah that was what I was looking for, the .length method which I can call directly as "<c:if test=$"{fn:length(aStoredProcedure) gt 1} and had it been tagged with JSP maybe I would have found it earlier :) thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do `'1'`, just use `1`

so

```
<c:if test="${ row > 1 }">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <%--do something here if it is bigger than 1--%>
  </td>
 </tr>
</c:if>
```

should work provided `row` is the integer number of rows.

There are some nice examples for jstl operators here http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/jsp/operators/relationalopr.php